# How to load balance with common database

Tags: postgresql, nginx, docker, flask, redis

I am using Docker to create a container for each of the following:
NGINX, Flask Application, Redis, PostgreSQL. I realize that Flask is not as powerful as a single node, so I want to load balance between multiple Flask instances. I am wondering how that would work.

Should I create multiple servers with the Flask container? How do I make sure they all use the same Redis instance and PostgreSQL database? Would this be a functional setup?

Containers by server:

```
Server 1: NGINX, Flask, Redis, PostgreSQL
Server 2: Flask
Server 3: Flask
```

Any other thoughts and tips?

Answer (score 1):

After quite a bit of research, I have found the setup that would fit the most my needs.

```
Server 1: NGINX
Server 2: Flask
Server 3: Flask
Server 4: Redis and PostgreSQL
```

This way, all requests go to NGINX, which load balances between the 2 Flask servers. Finally, the Flask servers access the common data server having both Redis and PostgreSQL.

@VonC Thank you for your proposition. Unfortunately, I already have everything set up in regards to container organization and SSL. I just did not know how to organize them!

Answer (score 0):

You could run your containers behind [Traefik](https://traefik.io/), a "HTTP reverse proxy and load balancer made to deploy microservices with ease".

See for instance "[Running your application over HTTPS with traefik](http://beenje.github.io/blog/posts/running-your-application-over-https-with-traefik/)".
His project [beenje/flask_traefik_letsencrypt](https://github.com/beenje/flask_traefik_letsencrypt) use a [flask container](https://github.com/beenje/flask_traefik_letsencrypt/blob/master/flask/Dockerfile), with [traefik settings](https://github.com/beenje/flask_traefik_letsencrypt/blob/master/docker-compose.yml#L8-L10).

You can then scale that service to multiple flask containers.